# Where is RichFacesAjaxHandler?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-webflow

I'm producing a small example to [solve a problem I'm having in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747986/nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-requestmapping-pathljava-lang-string). In one of my tests, I had this message from Tomcat:

```
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.faces.richfaces.RichFacesAjaxHandler
```

This came from this configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    <property name="ajaxHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.faces.richfaces.RichFacesAjaxHandler" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

`spring-faces` is installed through Maven, version `2.4.4.RELEASE` (the same of `spring-webflow`). Inspecting the jar to check the packages, I got:

[image: Spring-Faces]

Curiously, [1Maven says that the file is there](https://www.1maven.com/sources/org.springframework.webflow:spring-faces:2.3.4.RELEASE/RichFacesAjaxHandler). Now comes my question:

Where is `RichFacesAjaxHandler`? If is not contained in `spring-faces`, which package contains the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Spring removed RichFaces support in version 2.4 of Spring Web Flow. I downgraded `spring-faces` package to version [`2.3.4.RELEASE`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/spring-faces/2.3.4.RELEASE) to get the application working again:

[image: RichFacesAjazHandler]